# AuthLogic one time password (persistence_token) - what config is required to use this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

Can anyone confirm what config exactly is required to make the one time password (persistence_token) work?

From what I can work out so far it is the following, however this isn't working for me so I must be wrong:

- pass an additional URL parameter of "user_credentials=xxxxpersistence_tokenxxxx"
- question - are there any other URL parameters required beyond this?  any user id or username?
- have the persistence_token field in my database table (which it is and I can see it populated)
- have "acts _as _authentic " in my user model per normal
- question: is "acts _as _authentic " required in each of my own models?

When I enter a URL in the browser directly to one of my own model resources following the above I see in the logs:

(a) initial request - Redirected to http://localhost:3000/user_session/new

(b) and then for this redirect:

```
Processing UserSessionsController#new (for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-12-03
06:14:24) [GET]
  Parameters: {"action"=>"new", "controller"=>"user_sessions"}
  User Columns (3.4ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `users`
  User Indexes (0.9ms)   SHOW KEYS FROM `users`
Rendering template within layouts/application
Rendering user_sessions/new
  SQL (0.6ms)   SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM `users` WHERE
(last_request_at > '2009-12-02 20:04:24')
Completed in 182ms (View: 151, DB: 5) | 200 OK [http://localhost/
user_session/new]
```

(c) But then the web-page ends up on the login page, and not
automatically on the page I was after - i.e. I was expecting that the
one-time password would allow AuthLogic to automatically do the
session and then authentication?

Thanks

PS. Wonder if it related to this authlogic code I found in params.rb

```
def single_access_allowed_request_types(value = nil)
  rw_config(:single_access_allowed_request_types, value, ["application/rss+xml", "application/atom+xml"])
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have have it now. I did:

- Pass the parameter (not header) of user_credentials=<>
- Have the single_access_token column in your users table
- Put the following method in the users_controller:

> ```
> private
>   def single_access_allowed?
>     true
>   end
> ```

- For other controllers (i.e. besides application, user, user_sessions) 
  I put: "before_filter :require_user"  (not sure if there's a way to do this in the 
  controller that would handle it automatically?)

thanks